# How do I convert points column values in rank order in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
id1      id2        Points
1         1a          0.34
1         1a          0.34
1         2a          0.23
1         3a          0.71   
2         73a         0.52
2         43a         0.2
2         43a         0.2
2         34a         0.83
3         23a         0.53
3         9a3         0.13
```

Ok, so here is the thing. If `id1` and `id2` are same of multiple rows, then `points` are also same of those rows.

I want to convert those points to rank. Different for different `id1`. If two people have same `id1` and `id2`, then the rank will also be same

Expected output:

```
id1      id2        Points     Rank
1         1a          0.34      2
1         1a          0.34      2
1         2a          0.23      3
1         3a          0.71      1
2         73a         0.52      2
2         43a         0.2       3
2         43a         0.2       3
2         34a         0.83      1
3         23a         0.53      1
3         9a3         0.13      2
```

Let me know, If I am not clearl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with parameters `dense` and `ascending=False`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('id1')['Points'].rank('dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
   id1  id2  Points  new
0    1   1a    0.34    2
1    1   1a    0.34    2
2    1   2a    0.23    3
3    1   3a    0.71    1
4    2  73a    0.52    2
5    2  43a    0.20    3
6    2  43a    0.20    3
7    2  34a    0.83    1
8    3  23a    0.53    1
9    3  9a3    0.13    2
```

Comment: You answered most of my questions. From where you learned so many things about Pandas? I tired to read documentation, but it is really very hard to understand from it.

Comment: @JohnDoe - Yes, I agree, for first time is is not easy. I really like [tutorials, especially modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas).

Comment: Hey, your answer do not include `id2` anywhere. How is this working?

Comment: @JohnDoe - It working because for `id2` are same `Points` per groups.